# popup a dialog and submit partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

So what I am trying to do here is that in the View,

1. when I click on the button, I want to pass some values generated from the foreach loop (in my case Country and City) to the javascript function.
2. Inside that javascript function, I want to open up a dialog(partial view) by passing those values (countryName, cityName) to the controller.
3. Hence in my controller, it will pass those values to the partial view which will be appeared as a dialog and can submit the form.

I've tried with the version without the pop-up dialog (it worked), but having a hard time doing it with a dialog. #3 works btw, but I think I am having a trouble with #1 and #2. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<test.Models.Employee>

<table class="table">
<tr>    
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th>       
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) { 
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
    </td>       
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>   
    <td>
        <button onclick="OpenDialog(item.Country, item.City)">
            Open Dialog
        </button>           
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<div id="dialog"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>

<script>
function OpenDialog(countryName, cityName) {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'My Table',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {

            $(this).load('@Url.Action("getEmployee", "Employee", new
                     {
                         country = countryName,
                         city = cityName
                     })');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    }
</script>

}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult getEmployee(string country, string city)
    {
        var viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            Country = country,
            City = city
        };

        return PartialView("EmployeeDialog", viewModel);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model test.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostEmployee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.City)        
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)       

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>          

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor code and is parsed in the server before its sent to the view. `countryName` and `cityName` are javascript variables and do not even exist at that point (they are not in scope). Change the code in the `OpenDialog()` function to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("getEmployee", "Employee")';
var data = { country: countryName, city: cityName };
$(this).load(url, data);
```

As a side note, there is really no need to be calling the server each time to return values that you already have in the view. You could just render the form in the dialog initially (for a default `EmployeeViewModel` and then in the `OpenDialog` just set the values of the inputs for properties `Country` and `City`, for example `$('#Country').val(countryName);`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I don't quite get the last part (side note) Do you mean that I can put 

'@using (Html.BeginForm("PostEmployee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.City)        
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)       

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>          

}' in the OpenDialog function?

Comment: oops, sorry for the mess

Comment: Yes, but you would need to use `@Html.Action()` or `Html.Partial()` to generate the form. Your model is `IEnumerable<Employee>` which does not contain and properties (you would not be able to use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country)` in the main view because it would throw an exception)

Comment: Okay, let's say I used Html.Partial("EmployeeViewModel") in the opendialog function, but I am not sure how to pass those values(country, city) at the same time

Comment: You just render a form based on a default model - it will contain `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Country)` etc which will generate `<input id="Country" .../>` Then in the first line of the `OpenDialog()` function, `$('#Country').val(countryName);` (ditto for `City`) to populate the controls. Then all you need to do is `.show()` the dialog rather that calling the server. And you dont put `@Html.Partial()` in the script - you just render it in the view - between you `<div id="dialog"></div>` tags

Comment: Stephen, I tried with your code but I have 'Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenDialog is not defined' error in the Console. This happened before too. Is that related to jquery.ui import?

Comment: That's not related to the code you have shown (but its related to your scripts). In any case you should not be polluting your mark-up with behavior - its the 21st century so use [Unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). And refer [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) to understand what I mean

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you